# Mongo with CI unknown output

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am new to `MongoDB` and and I am trying to connect it with `CI`. I am following [this](http://www.phpgainers.com/content/how-use-mongo-db-codeigniter) tutorial and when I run my controller, it shows me some thing like this

```
MongoCollection Object
(
    [w] => 0
    [wtimeout] => 10000
)
```

I am not sure if I am connected to the db or not.

```
class sample extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->library('mongo_db');
        $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('tblusers');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection);
        exit;
    }

}
```

and when i do the `find()` on this `collection`, it gives me empty result set

```
function index() {
        $this->load->library('mongo_db');
        $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('tblusers');
        $result =   $collection->find();
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($result);
    }
```

Comment: please, include all information from the beginning. It is hard to give answers, if you modify your question often. Are you sure you are connected to a correct database?

Comment: @SalvadorDali well i am triggering to the correc tone and this `db` exists on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are connected to DB. Moreover you already selected a collection, because you received a [collection object](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.selectcollection.php). You can verify that you connected to it, by starting querying your collection.